# How to stop logging of XMLFileChanges in InstallShield?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installscript-msi

I have InstallShield project for one installer. I have added XML File Changes in that. These XML file changes have some data which I'm adding in the XML file during installation. All the XML file changes are getting logged into log file. But I don't want to log these statements of XML file changes into log file. How I can prevent this from logging into log file?

Comment: Have you tried the MsiHiddenProperties as [described in the Installshield Help File](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/HidingProperty.htm)? (not tested). And [for UI/Suite projects](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/ISHiddenProperties.htm). Then use properties as the values you inject in the XML file?

Comment: I'm aware of MsiHiddenProperties, but there are lot of attributes we are adding to XML during install. So I will require to add new properties for each attributes, this will not be an efficient solution , I think.

Comment: Maybe try the [Installshield Community](http://community.installshield.com) (user forums - or support if you have a support agreement?). I don't use this feature much. Also consider the possibility of updating the XML files via your application launch sequence if they are per-user XML settings files. More reliable, easier to debug and better control.